How to write a struct with an array of structs to file with foundry vm.writeJson?
In the parseJson segment of the foundry documentation book, one can see an example of a struct with an array of structs:
{
    "apples": [
        {
            "sweetness": 7,
            "sourness": 3,
            "color": "Red"
        },
        {
            "sweetness": 5,
            "sourness": 5,
            "color": "Green"
        },
        {
            "sweetness": 9,
            "sourness": 1,
            "color": "Yellow"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Fresh Fruit"
}

And one can read that from file with:
string memory root = vm.projectRoot();
string memory path = string.concat(root, "/src/test/fixtures/fruitstall.json");
string memory json = vm.readFile(path);
bytes memory data = vm.parseJson(json);
FruitStall memory fruitstall = abi.decode(data, (FruitStall));

// Logs: Welcome to Fresh Fruit
console2.log("Welcome to", fruitstall.name);

for (uint256 i = 0; i < fruitstall.apples.length; i++) {
    Apple memory apple = fruitstall.apples[i];

    // Logs:
    // Color: Red, Sourness: 3, Sweetness: 7
    // Color: Green, Sourness: 5, Sweetness: 5
    // Color: Yellow, Sourness: 1, Sweetness: 9
    console2.log(
        "Color: %s, Sourness: %d, Sweetness: %d",
        apple.color,
        apple.sourness,
        apple.sweetness
    );
}

However, I am experiencing some difficulties in starting with the struct, and writing that to json (such that it can be read in again). I was not able to find the counter-example in the writeJson segment of the foundry book. Hence I would like to ask:
How can one write the above Fruitstall struct to json, such that it can be read back in again?

It's slightly complicated. To be honest, I've taken help from ChatGPT in order to come up with the approach, and have broken the process down into functions including getFruitStall(), serializeApples() and serializeFruitStall(), so as to make it a bit modularized and reusable.
Provided that you've created an empty JSON file named as fruitstall.json inside script/target folder.
WriteJson.s.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {Script, console2} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {Strings} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract WriteJson is Script {
    struct Apple {
        string color;
        uint8 sourness;
        uint8 sweetness;
    }

    struct FruitStall {
        Apple[] apples;
        string name;
    }

    function run() public {
        writeJson("script/target/fruitstall.json");
    }

    function getFruitStall() public pure returns (FruitStall memory) {
        // Initialize an array of Apple structs

        Apple[] memory apples = new Apple[](3);
        apples[0] = Apple({color: "Red", sourness: 3, sweetness: 7});
        apples[1] = Apple({color: "Green", sourness: 5, sweetness: 5});
        apples[2] = Apple({color: "Yellow", sourness: 1, sweetness: 9});

        // Initialize the FruitStall struct 
        FruitStall memory fruitstall = FruitStall({apples: apples, name: "Fresh Fruit"});

        return fruitstall;
    }

    // Function to serialize the apples array
    function serializeApples(Apple[] memory apples) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string[] memory applesJson = new string[](apples.length);

        // Serialize each apple object
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < apples.length; i++) {
            string memory appleJson = "{";
            appleJson = string(abi.encodePacked(appleJson, "\"color\":\"", apples[i].color, "\","));
            appleJson = string(abi.encodePacked(appleJson, "\"sourness\":", Strings.toString(apples[i].sourness), ","));
            appleJson = string(abi.encodePacked(appleJson, "\"sweetness\":", Strings.toString(apples[i].sweetness)));
            appleJson = string(abi.encodePacked(appleJson, "}"));
            applesJson[i] = appleJson;
        }

        // Combine the apples array into a JSON array
        string memory applesJsonArray = "[";
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < applesJson.length; i++) {
            applesJsonArray = string(abi.encodePacked(applesJsonArray, applesJson[i]));
            if (i < applesJson.length - 1) {
                applesJsonArray = string(abi.encodePacked(applesJsonArray, ","));
            }
        }
        applesJsonArray = string(abi.encodePacked(applesJsonArray, "]"));

        return applesJsonArray;
    }

    // Function to serialize the FruitStall object to JSON
    function serializeFruitStall() public pure returns (string memory) {
        // Get the FruitStall data
        FruitStall memory fruitstall = getFruitStall();

        // Serialize apples using the serializeApples function
        string memory applesJsonArray = serializeApples(fruitstall.apples);

        // Final JSON string combining apples and name
        string memory finalJson = "{";
        finalJson = string(abi.encodePacked(finalJson, "\"apples\":", applesJsonArray, ","));
        finalJson = string(abi.encodePacked(finalJson, "\"name\":\"", fruitstall.name, "\""));
        finalJson = string(abi.encodePacked(finalJson, "}"));

        return finalJson;
    }

    function writeJson(string memory path) public {
        // Write the final JSON to the file
        vm.writeJson(serializeFruitStall(), path);
    }
}

When you execute this script using the command:
forge script script/WriteJson.s.sol

The content of fruitstall.json would become:
{
  "apples": [
    {
      "color": "Red",
      "sourness": 3,
      "sweetness": 7
    },
    {
      "color": "Green",
      "sourness": 5,
      "sweetness": 5
    },
    {
      "color": "Yellow",
      "sourness": 1,
      "sweetness": 9
    }
  ],
  "name": "Fresh Fruit"
}

Then, you can simply read that file and store the JSON into a variable of type FruitStall struct using the following script (as given in the doc):
ReadJson.s.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {Script, console2} from "forge-std/Script.sol";

contract ReadJson is Script {
    struct Apple {
        string color;
        uint8 sourness;
        uint8 sweetness;
    }

    struct FruitStall {
        Apple[] apples;
        string name;
    }

    function run() public view {
        readJson("/script/target/fruitstall.json");
    }

    function readJson(string memory path) public view {
        string memory root = vm.projectRoot();
        string memory fullPath = string.concat(root, path);
        string memory json = vm.readFile(fullPath);
        bytes memory data = vm.parseJson(json);
        FruitStall memory fruitstall = abi.decode(data, (FruitStall));

        console2.log("Welcome to", fruitstall.name);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < fruitstall.apples.length; i++) {
            Apple memory apple = fruitstall.apples[i];

            console2.log("Color: %s, Sourness: %d, Sweetness: %d", apple.color, apple.sourness, apple.sweetness);
        }
    }
}

When you execute this script using the command:
forge script script/ReadJson.s.sol -vvv

The output would be:

P.S., As per the structure and fields of your struct, you need to change some logic accordingly. And, ChatGPT or any other generative AI that you're comfortable with, would come handy for doing such modifications.
